# Is there a way to use independent CASE statements in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, case

I am trying to find distinct items in two tables and store them in a column. Which table to obtain item from depends upon certain conditions. But both tables are to be checked even if there is a match with first condition.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CASE WHEN condition1 then table1.column
                     WHEN condition2 then table2.column END)
```

Assuming tables are joined appropriately, is it possible to achieve this using CASE statements?

Comment: what you are saying sounds easily possible, but isn't very clear.  please provide some sample data and expected results for that sample data

Comment: (1) DISTINCT is **not** a function, it is applied to the whole output row. Your parenthesis makes no sense and may become syntax error if you'll wrap more than one column expression; (2) If you'll remove the parenthesis then the construction will be absolutely legal. [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=597df1026c4c5bd807e269acee471b5a)